# Python Object return a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-class

I have a Deck class from which i create a deck Object:

```py
class Deck:
  cards = []

deck = Deck()
```

How can  I make the deck object to return the cards list when called?

```py
print(deck)

# or

for card in deck:
  # do
```

Without having to always call deck.cards?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could define `__iter__` in class `Deck`:

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [1, 2, 3]

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in self.cards:
            yield i


deck = Deck()
for card in deck:
    print(card)
```

And this print:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to `__iter__(self):` you could also use `__call__(self):`. With the latter you would have to append parentheses to `deck`, though, like so: `deck()`.

What's best really depends on the context of your app / code.

```py
class Deck:
    cards = [1, 2, 3]

    def __call__(self):
        return self.cards

deck = Deck()

print(deck())
```

output: `[1, 2, 3]`

```py
for card in deck():
  print(card)
```

output:

```
1
2
3
```

I have researched the dunder method here: [Python Dunder Methods](https://dbader.org/blog/python-dunder-methods). The author writes that using separate class methods is usually better, since they are more specific.

Maybe you could provide some more context on why you'd want to use `deck` instead of `deck.cards`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a way:

```
import jsons


class Deck:
    cards = ['card_1', 'card_2', 'card_3']


deck = Deck()

dict_temp = jsons.dump(deck)
print(dict_temp['cards'])

=>
['card_1', 'card_2', 'card_3']
```

Comment: @MelvinAbraham, correct me if I am wrong, but I don't see an usage of deck.cards in my solution. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer might not be wrong but clearly the OP doesn't want to include any methods, attributes, etc. when iterating through `card`

Comment: Also, you might have a typo in your code. Instead of `jsons` probably you meant `json`. On top of that it throws an error in the line `json.dump`.

Comment: @MelvinAbraham, it's actually a separate module with slightly different characteristics. Check it out if you wish.